# How do i run a program without using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have made a program on visual studio (2019) and want to run it without using the debugging mode without visual studio open.

Answer (score 0):

Debug > Start without Debugging.

The shortcut is Ctrl-F5.

Edit: After building, you can simply launch the executable code in the build output folder. For example, for an executable C# .NET project, this will be something like `/MyProject/bin/Debug/MyProject.exe`
where `MyProject` is your project's name, and Debug will be the configuration name (e.g. Debug, Release, x86, etc).